# Terraform Throwing Error while doing Init with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to run Terraform with Azure DevOps
Below is my pipeline YML file

```
variables:
  - group: infra-variables
  
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - Terraform-Test 
    exclude:
    - README.md
  
stages:
- stage: Validate
  displayName: Validate
  jobs:
  - job: validate
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - checkout : self 
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName : 
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'PalTest'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          az account set --subscription $AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
          az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID 
          STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY=$(az storage account keys list -g $(Terraform_Backend_RG) -n $(TF_STATE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME) | jq ".[0].value" -r)
          echo "setting storage account key variable"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_ACCESS_KEY;issecret=true]$ARM_ACCESS_KEY"

    - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
      displayName: Install Terraform
      inputs:
        terraformVersion: 'latest'


  # Init
    - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
      displayName: "Terraform Init"
      inputs:
        provider : 'azurerm'
        command: 'init'
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-Test'
        backendServiceArm: 'PalTest'
        backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: $(Terraform_Backend_RG)
        backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: $(TF_STATE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME)
        backendAzureRmContainerName: '$(TF_STATE_BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME)'
        backendAzureRmKey: 'infrastructure/terraform.tfstate'

  # Validate
    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: Validate Config
      inputs:
        command: 'validate'
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-Test'

- stage: Plan
  displayName: Plan
  jobs:
  - job: plan
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
      displayName: Install Terraform
      inputs:
        terraformVersion: 'latest'

  # Init
    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: Initialize Terraform
      env:
        ARM_SAS_TOKEN: $(ARM_ACCESS_KEY)
      inputs:
        command: 'init'
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-Test'
        commandOptions: '-backend-config=storage_account_name=$(TF_STATE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME) -backend-config=container_name=$(TF_STATE_BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME) -backend-config=key=$(ARM_ACCESS_KEY)'
        backendType: 'selfConfigured'

  # Plan
    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: Plan Terraform Deployment
      env:
        ARM_SAS_TOKEN: $(ARM_ACCESS_KEY)
        ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(AZURE_CLIENT_ID)
        ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET)
        ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
        ARM_TENANT_ID: $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)
      inputs:
        command: 'plan'
        commandOptions: '-input=false'
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-Test'

# Approve
- stage: Approve
  displayName: Approve
  jobs:
  - job: approve
    displayName: Wait for approval
    pool: server
    steps: 
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 60
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: 'pallabcd@hotmail.com'
        instructions: 'Review the plan in the next hour'

- stage: Apply
  displayName: Apply
  jobs:
  - job: apply
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
        displayName: Install Terraform
        inputs:
          terraformVersion: 'latest'
      
      # Init
      - task: TerraformCLI@0
        displayName: TF Init 
        env:
          ARM_SAS_TOKEN: $(ARM_ACCESS_KEY)
        inputs:
          command: 'init'
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-Test'
          commandOptions: '-backend-config=storage_account_name=$(TF_STATE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME) -backend-config=container_name=$(TF_STATE_BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME) -backend-config=key=$(ARM_ACCESS_KEY)'
          backendType: 'selfConfigured'


      # Apply
      - task: TerraformCLI@0
        displayName: TF Apply 
        env:
          ARM_SAS_TOKEN: $(ARM_ACCESS_KEY)
          ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(AZURE_CLIENT_ID)
          ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET)
          ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
          ARM_TENANT_ID: $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)
        inputs:
          command: 'apply'
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-Test'
          commandOptions: '-auto-approve'
```

My main.tf file is shown below :

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.0"

  backend "azurerm" {
  storage_account_name = "glstor2020"
  container_name = "glstor2050" 
  key = "terraform.tfstate"
  access_key = "=="
}
  
  required_providers {
    azuread = "~> 1.0"  
    azurerm = "~> 2.0"
  }
}


provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "az-rg-wu" {
  name = "Great-Learning"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "my-kv" {
  name                = "testhalvault"
  resource_group_name = "PallabDev"
}
```

All my variables are in variable group and below is my tfvar file which takes variable from the variable group

```
subscription_id      = "#{AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}#"
client_id            = "#{AZURE_CLIENT_ID}#"  
client_secret        = "#{AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET}#" 
tenant_id            = "#{AZURE_TENANT_ID}#" 
storage_account_name = "#{TF_STATE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME}#" 
container_name       = "#{TF_STATE_BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME}#" 
access_key           = "#{ARM_ACCESS_KEY}#"
admin_password       = "#{VM_PWD}#"
```

I get the below error in the init stage

[image]

Comment: Hi Pallab, did the answer posted on the ticket help you? If it helps, just as a remind of [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks for your kindness :-) .

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/azurerm

In your example it seems that you use 3 approaches, maybe terraform chooses one of these(deciding by which argument was provided first), and after you provide other properties it is a problem for Terraform

You use access_key

> When authenticating using the Storage Account's Access Key - the following fields are also supported: access_key

You also use sas_token

> When authenticating using a SAS Token associated with the Storage Account - the following fields are also supported:

You also use client_secret and other which can be found in section

> When authenticating using a Service Principal with a Client Secret - the following fields are also supported:

I am not sure if Azure can handle all these 3 directions at once